# stop indicator in asynchronous downloading

Tags: iphone, multithreading

I am adding all image downloading operation into Nsoperationqueue. But some times indicator will display for forever. Here I have paste some of my code. Is there any way to stop indicator. Here I am checking "operationcount". If it will become 1 means its last operation so I am stoping indicator but sometimes its not working any help will be appreciated.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {
//filename = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.iconImage];
myobject.iconImage  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:self.filename];
myobject.isImageLoaded = YES;

[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
finished = YES;
executing = NO;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"]; 


NSLog(@"finsh");

AboutUSAppDelegate *appdel=(AboutUSAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSLog(@"%d",[appdel.queue operationCount]);
if ([appdel.queue operationCount]==1) {
    //code to stop indicator 
    //Using main thread
}
```

Here I have added Nslog for operation count but sometimes it prints last value 2 two times. other values only 1 times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that all UI calls are made on the main thread of operation. So showing the activity indicator, making it spin, stopping it and hiding it all need to be done on the main thread.

A reasonable way to achieve this is to expose methods in your view controllers to do it and from inside your Operation code call them on the main :-

Look up

```
performSelectorOnMainThread:<(SEL)aSelector> withObject:<(id)arg> waitUntilDone:<(BOOL)wait>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.I have already did that just see inside my if condition I have mentioned that "Using main thread"

Comment: You should also move check if count <= 1 to somewhere outside of NSOperation. I usually have delegate methods or blocks to notify operation has finished. Anyway, those operations you execute are being processed in parallel on several threads causing race condition this situation.

Comment: count<=1 also not working because sometimes last value in nslog displayed only - 2.You are right here threads are causing race condtion. Is there any way or delegate method that will notify when operation completed?

Comment: addOperations:waitUntilFinished: from background thread is one solution. Also, tracking number of operations added to queue vs operations finished is another

Comment: can you provide any sample for it. or rough code that can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, you can not check the operation queue in the delegate method implementation. This method get called when only 1 of the operation queue get done, it will not be called by any other methods in your queue.

Check the queue where you initialized them.

Comment: This method will be called for every opertion once because all operation are about downloading image. If I am getting wrong the please explain more